# Classes, Privates through Publics

Tags: c++, class, private, public

i am trying to understand how can i access private classes through public classes because some experts said to me that i have to use only private classes. But i can't understand why this doesn't work.I really don't know how can i access private through public its really confusing .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ManolisClass{

public :
    void setName(string x){
        name = x;
    }

    string getName(){
        return name;
    }

private :
    string name;
};

int main()
{
    ManolisClass bo;
    getline(cin, bo.setName() );
    cout << bo.getName();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Access private classes through public classes? Are you talking about inheritance? I am confused

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it compile? Does it yield an unexpected result? Please expand your question.

Comment: sorry, i am really sorry...but i am learning this now! they said to me that i have to use ONLY private classes and never public.

Comment: When people say to use private data members, they don't mean to expose all of them with setters and getters. That ruins the point of any abstraction your class does.

Comment: Your `getline` call is wrong! You pass it the *result* of the `setName` member function call, but it doesn't return anything. The `setName` function also needs an input argument, which you do not provide. You need to store the input in a temporary variable, and call `setName` with this variable.

Comment: Pass the string to setName as const reference to avoid a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access methods are correct, but as you can see from the signature of the function setName, you have to provide a string to set the name of the class. `getLine` method takes a string as argument. You could create an intermediate variable and use that variable to set the name of the class.

Here is how one can do it.

```
string temp;
getline(cin, temp);
bo.setName(temp);
```

Comment: thanks! thats what i want! thank you so much! some experts said to me that i have to use only private classes because the public classes are bad programming, i am learning now so i have to listen to them ! thank you